# Count values based on multiple key values in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have a `result array` in php. I want to count values based on multiple key values. For example:

I want to count all departure which belongs to "fromcity" => Lahore and  "tocity" => Sahiwal

And also same all other fromcity and tocity departure counts.

As like group by statement.

Kindly help me out in it.

I have a following result array in php:

```
$result_array = array
    (
        [0] => array
            (
                "id" => "348",
                "departure" => "00:00:00",
                "fromcity" => "Lahore",
                "tocity" => "Buhawalpur"
            )

        [1] => array
            (
                "id" => "531",
                "departure" => "00:00:00",
                "fromcity" => "Lahore",
                "tocity" => "Murree"
            )

        [2] => array
            (
                "id" => "532",
                "departure" => "00:00:00",
                "fromcity" => "Lahore",
                "tocity" => "Rawalpindi"
            )

        [3] => array
            (
                "id" => "581",
                "departure" => "00:00:00",
                "fromcity" => "Lahore",
                "tocity" => "Multan"
            )

        [4] => array
            (
                "id" => "582",
                "departure" => "00:00:00",
                "fromcity" => "Lahore",
                "tocity" => "Sahiwal"
            )

        [5] => array
            (
                "id" => "528",
                "departure" => "00:05:00",
                "fromcity" => "Lahore",
                "tocity" => "Sahiwal"
            )

        [6] => array
            (
                "id" => "1584",
                "departure" => "00:15:00",
                "fromcity]" => "Lahore",
               "tocity]"=> "Multan"
            )

        [7] => array
            (
                "id" => "1586",
                "departure" => "00:15:00",
                "fromcity"=> "Lahore",
                "tocity" => "Sahiwal"
            )

        [8] => array
            (
                "id" => "349",
                "departure" => "01:00:00",
                "fromcity" => "Lahore",
                "tocity" => "Multan"
            )

        [9] => array
            (
                "id" => "529",
                "departure" => "01:00:00",
                "fromcity" => "Lahore",
                "tocity" => "Sahiwal"
            )

        [10] => array
            (
                "id" => "906",
                "departure" => "01:00:00",
                "fromcity" => "Lahore",
                "tocity" => "Rawalpindi"
            )

        [11] => array
            (
                "id" => "685",
                "departure" => "01:45:00",
                "fromcity" => "Lahore",
                "tocity" => "Rawalpindi"
            )

        [12] => array
            (
                "id" => "350",
                "departure" => "02:00:00",
                "fromcity" => "Lahore",
                "tocity" => "Multan"
            )

        [13] => array
            (
                "id" => "530",
                "departure" => "02:00:00",
                "fromcity" => "Lahore",
                "tocity" => "Sahiwal"
            )

        [14] => array
            (
                "id" => "907",
                "departure" => "02:30:00",
                "fromcity" => "Lahore",
                "tocity" => "Rawalpindi"
            )

        [15] => array
            (
                "id" => "736",
                "departure" => "03:15:00",
                "fromcity" => "Lahore",
                "tocity" => "Sahiwal"
            )

        [16] => array
            (
                "id" => "908",
                "departure" => "05:30:00",
                "fromcity" => "Lahore",
                "tocity" => "Rawalpindi"
            )

        [17] => array
            (
                "id" => "1649",
                "departure" => "05:30:00",
                "fromcity"=> "Lahore",
                "tocity" => "Faislabad"
            )

        [18] => array
            (
                "id" => "331",
                "departure" => "06:00:00",
                "fromcity" => "Lahore",
                "tocity" => "Multan"
            )

        [19] => array
            (
                "id" => "438",
                "departure" => "06:00:00",
                "fromcity" => "Lahore",
                "tocity" => "Sialkot"
            )

        [20] => array
            (
                "id" => "447",
                "departure" => "06:00:00",
                "fromcity" => "Lahore",
                "tocity" => "Daska"
            )

    )
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include your attempts at achieving the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement this by yourself. Simply iterate over the `$result_array` and count what you need:

```
$counter = 0;
foreach($result_array as $item) {
  if($item['fromcity'] == 'Lahore' and $item['tocity'] == 'Sahiwal') {
    $counter++;
  }
}

echo "My current count is " . $counter;
```

You probably want to implment a count function that will just return the counter.

Comment: @Ivanka Todorova , if i want to count all values , then i need to put so many if else conditions . so that this not full fill my requirements. i want to count all departures group by all cities. the result array i need is                         Lahore To Sahiwal (10)

Comment: sorry the result array i need is such type: lahore to sahiwal (8) ; lahore to multan (6) ; multan to islamabad (7)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to group based on `fromcity` and `tocity`, you can do the following:

```
$count = [];
foreach($result_array as $element) {
   $search = $element['fromcity']. '-'. $element['tocity'];
   if(!isset($count[$search])) {
      $count[$search] = 1;
   } else {
      $count[$search] += 1;
   }
}

//Result: 
foreach($count as $name => $cnt) {
 echo $name.' - '. $cnt .PHP_EOL;
}
```