# How to count array values based on two columns in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array (from a Salesforce SOQL) that has multiple results (74 to be exact). Each array has keys and values as follows:

```
array {
    ["ID"] => "Project ID"
    ["Name"] => "Project Name"
    ["Project Type"] => "Type Name"
    ["Project Stage"] => "Stage Name"
    ["Value"] => "Amount"
    ["Capacity"] => "Number"
    ["Project Group 1"] => "Group Name"
    ["Project Group 2"] => "Group Name"
    ["Project Group 3"] => "Group Name"
    ["Project Group 4"] => "Group Name"
}
```

I want to count the number of results depending on **both** the Project Type and a Project Group so I can flip those results into an array used for generating a CSV.

I'm currently able to count the number of results depending on the Project Group value using `array_count_values` and `array_column`. Here's the code for that result:

```
// Project Group 1 Totals
$results = array_count_values(array_column($array, 'Project Group 1'));
foreach($results as $key => $value) {
    if($key === 'Group Name (1)') $key = 'New Group Name (1)';
    if($key === 'Group Name (2)') $key = 'New Group Name (2)';
    $csv_array = array('New Project Group 1 Name', $key, $value);
    fputcsv($output, $csv_array);
}

// Results
array {
    [0] => "New Project Group 1 Name"
    [1] => "New Group Name (1)"
    [2] => (Number)
}
array {
    [0] => "New Project Group 1 Name"
    [1] => "New Group Name (2)"
    [2] => (Number)
}
```

Any way on how I can split these results up for each Project Type, so that the final CSV array can look as follows?

```
array {
    [0] => "New Project Group 1 Name"
    [1] => "New Group Name (1)"
    [2] => (Number)
    [3] => "Project Type Name"
}
array {
    [0] => "New Project Group 1 Name"
    [1] => "New Group Name (2)"
    [2] => (Number)
    [3] => "Project Type Name"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. I figured this out.

Thanks to this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/39035322/4220832), I got the idea to stop using `array_count_values` and `array_column` and just work in two separate `foreach` loops.

Here's the solution:

```
$count = [];
foreach($array as $result) {
    $search = $result['Project Type'] . ',' . $result['Project Group 1'];
    if(!isset($count[$search])) {
        $count[$search] = 1;
    } else {
        $count[$search] += 1;
    }
}
foreach($count as $key => $value) {
    if($key === 'Project Type,Old Project Group Value') $key = 'Project Type,New Project Group Value';
    $split = explode(',', $key);
    $csv_array = array($split[0], $split[1], 'New Project Group 1 Name', $value);
    //echo'<pre>';print_r($csv_array);echo'</pre>'; // For Testing Purposes To Use
    fputcsv($output, $csv_array);
}
```

I hope this discovery helps whoever needs it. It's probably best to streamline this solution into a workable function in your project to use over and over.